# ConcurrentMap with keeping order

Tags: java, data-structures, java.util.concurrent

I would like to have possibilities like `ConcurrentMap` gives me so:

- thread-safe
- performance-efficient
- Id indicator as a key
- object in a value
- random-access to specific elements

And additionally, I would like to keep the order in which the messages are stored.
Do anyone know which structure could fulfil the requirements or should I write my own implementation? Maybe anyone knows any useful library for such a problem?

I thought about `ConcurrentNavigableMap` as it is an extension of `SortedMap`. However, as I understand it well it will sort the elements in a specific order, not keep the order of inserting. I would also avoid having any `BlockingQueue` or `BlockingDeque` as I would like to have random access to specific elements.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391918/does-java-have-a-linkedconcurrenthashmap-data-structure

Comment: When your requirements are this specific, consider it likely that you're going to have to concede that it doesn't exist and write it yourself.

Comment: No, it's not @Jim - in the topic which you propose solutions doesn't have efficiency - Collections.synchronizedMap is slow and doesn't keep the order of insertion.

Comment: @RydA: the order of insertion is kept due to using a `LinkedHashMap` wrapped. As for the efficiency I would say if you haven't test it you can't know, and that it might be much faster than your custom solution. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid this will be the problem @Michael. But I will leave it here as maybe someone know any interesting library which solves the problem. Would be really nice to have it